# Pydantic v2 "Could not resolve reference: ..." error using custom response model

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

The docs (at `<host>:<port>/docs`) for this example:

```py
import pydantic
from fastapi import FastAPI


class Hour(int):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        h = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        assert 0 <= h < 24, f"Invalid hour: {h}"
        return h


class PydanticConfig:
    arbitrary_types_allowed = True


@pydantic.dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True, config=PydanticConfig)
class Time:
    hour: Hour


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/", response_model=Time)
def read_root():
    return Time(13)
```

Generate fine in `pydantic==1.10.9`.  In `pydantic==2.3.0`, they produce:

```
Errors
 
Resolver error at responses.200.content.application/json.schema.$ref
Could not resolve reference: Evaluation failed on token: "components"
Resolver error at responses.200.content.application/json.schema.$ref
Could not resolve reference: Evaluation failed on token: "components"
```

Changing to `hour: int` works again, so it has something to do with the `NewType`.

How do I get the docs / schema to generate correctly in v2?

Comment: In this specific case, you should be able to use [Pydantic's `conint`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/types/#pydantic.types.conint). In the general case, look into the [custom data types documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/types/custom/#as-a-method-on-a-custom-type).

Comment: @M.O. Thank you.  These constrained types are pretty handy!  And I'll have a look at the docs for the more general cases (the docs a little denser than I was expecting for this type of thing).